# JQuery QTip plugin foreach function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, qtip

I have a problem with qtip plugin. Notting shown in qtip div when I mouseover a user avatar.
My code for listing users:

```
<% foreach (var user in Model){%>
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="<%=Html.Encode(user.showavatar())%>">    
    </div>
    <div class="username" style="display:none"> 
            <%=Html.Encode(user.Username) %> 
    </div>
<%}%>
```

My JQuery Code for show username when mouseover a user div.

```
$('.avatar').each(function () {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            content:  $(this).next('.username').html()
        },
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout'
    })
});
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Are you placing your jQuery code in the document ready function?

Comment: yes of course. but the problem is when i mouseover the qtip div occurs but it is empty.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it fixed your problem. Otherwise, please comment or edit your question w/ updates about exactly what problem you are seeing.

Comment: of course jonathan. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra nested "content" map. Change these lines:

```
        content: {
            content:  $(this).next('.username').html()
        },
```

to this:

```
        content: $(this).next('.username').html(),
```

Comment: thanks jonathan. i solved it in another way. but your answer is correct wiothout a doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.avatar').qtip({
    content: {
        content:  $(this).next('.username').html()
    },
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout'
});
```

Why you using each function?

Comment: because my partial view list more than one div with same class "avatar".

Comment: I'm guessing because he wants "this" to refer to the element so that `$(this).next('.username')` is different each time around the loop, so it corresponds to the correct username. In your code, the expression isn't enclosed in a function, so it gets evaluated once when called.